# Point displacement, rule based styling and symbol levels

Tags: qgis, symbology, style

So basically I have a point layer with double symbology that looks like this:

```
type = 1 (big dot red)
 ----status = 1 (small red)
 ----status = 2 (small blue)
 ----status = 3 (small green)
type = 2 (big dot blue)
 ----status = 1 (small red)
 ----status = 2 (small blue)
 ----status = 3 (small green)
type = 3 (big dot green)
 ----status = 1 (small red)
 ----status = 2 (small blue)
 ----status = 3 (small green)
```

[image]

Using symbol levels, it works fine showing the small dot in front of the big dot. The problem is that sometimes people can place multiple type dots overlapping on the same location (or same type). In other words in a single location there can be 3 type3 dots and 2 type1 dots

That's where point displacement comes in. Technically it should work perfectly if I just duplicate the layer using the same symbology. But it does not, even though the symbols levels are already set up properly, the point displacement seems to ignore this and do the following ignoring the inner small dot

[image]

The symbol levels are as follows

[image]

How to make my double symbology work with point displacement?

Comment: Please provide your current point displacement settings.

Comment: As a workaround, you can create a new SVG symbol that contains the 2 circles and 2 dynamic colors.

Comment: @Erik ive editted the op

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when clicking on each main category, I would uncheck the Symbol box.[image]

But then, if none of the categories have a symbol (because they are range based), everything will disappear. I had to create a ghost category with a transparent symbol in order for the real categories to appear.

[image]